# String Pattern Matching in Sql / Pl/sql

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I need to match a string to a pattern to validate the given string.

The given string could be like this 1234/5678.

I should validate the string in such a way that the first four and the last four characters will have to be numbers and they must be seperated by a slash.

How can I do this in SQL  or PL/SQL?

I tried different functions such as REGEXP_LIKE, REGEXP_REPLACE,REGEXP_SUBSTR.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: So what have you tried

Comment: how are you receiving the string? Is it in a column in a table, or will it be passed around in PL/SQL as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If this needs to be done in PL/SQL (e.g. you're validating user input, rather than data in a table), you can create a function to do the validation, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  v_str VARCHAR2(10);

  FUNCTION validate_string (in_str VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN regexp_like(in_str, '\d{4}/\d{4}');
  END validate_string;

  PROCEDURE validation_output (in_str VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF validate_string (in_str => in_str) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(in_str||': validated');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line(in_str||': not validated');
    END IF;
  END validation_output;
BEGIN
  v_str := '1234/5678';
  validation_output (v_str);
  v_str := '12/5678';
  validation_output (v_str);
  v_str := NULL;
  validation_output (v_str);
END;
/

1234/5678: validated
12/5678: not validated
: not validated
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using oracle you can user regexp_like
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php
if you are using mysql regexp or rlike
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html
for sqlserver IsMatch()
https://github.com/zzzprojects/Eval-SQL.NET/wiki/SQL-Server-Regex-%7C-Use-regular-expression-to-search,-replace-and-split-text-in-SQL#sql-regex---ismatch

ORACLE

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE COL REGEXP_LIKE REGULAREXP
```

MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE COL RLIKE REGULAREXP

SELECT * FROM T WHERE COL REGEXP REGULAREXP
```

Answer (score 0):

sample table:

```
SELECT * FROM ns_98;
4321/4567
43/45
43898/4521
4388/4521
43885/45215
4388///4521

SELECT a
FROM ns_98
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (a,'^[0-9]{4}/{1}[0-9]{4}$');

output:
4321/4567
4388/4521
```